# Docker - pdo_mysql (nginx + PHP7 + MariaDB + phpMyAdmin) Symfony + Doctrine

Tags: symfony, docker, pdo

I have a little bit problem with install pdo_mysql into my docker container.

In Symfony I got this error:

> PDOException  PDOException  DriverException
>   HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
>   An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

**Symfony - config.yml**

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM phpdockerio/php7-fpm:latest

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install vim mc apt-utils \
&& php7-pdo_mysql php7-pdo \
&& apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* 
/usr/share/doc/*

WORKDIR "/var/www/project"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.1"
services:

mysql:
  image: mariadb
  container_name: project-mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root


phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  container_name: project-pma
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8183:80
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: mysql
    PMA_USER: root
    PMA_PASSWORD: root

webserver:
  image: nginx:alpine
  container_name: project-websrv
  working_dir: /var/www/project
  volumes:
      - ../../Sources/project/trunk/src/:/var/www/project
      - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  links:
   - php-fpm

php-fpm:
  build: phpdocker/php-fpm
  container_name: project-php
  working_dir: /var/www/project
  volumes:
    - ../../Sources/project/trunk/src/:/var/www/project
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/99-
overrides.ini
  links:
    - mysql
```

**docker-compose ps**

```
d:\Work\DockerContainers\project>docker-compose ps
 Name                  Command             State          Ports
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
project -mariadb   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      3306/tcp
project -php       /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/php-fpm   Up      9000/tcp
project -pma       /run.sh phpmyadmin            Up      0.0.0.0:8183->80/tcp
project -websrv    nginx -g daemon off;          Up      0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp

d:\Work\DockerContainers\project>
```

I have this linux version:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
```

I tried to change the package names for pdo_mysql in Dockerfile what I found on the forums, I tried installing through apt-get install directly in the container, but nothing helped I always get the same message:

```
/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-install: not found (docker-compose build)
E: Unable to locate package php7-mysql (pdo_mysql etc.) (root in docker container)
```

**php-ini-overrides.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 108M
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

I don´t know if is this problem in Symfony configuration or problem with docker

Can you help me, please?

Thanks a lot

Comment: why are you not using the official php docker image?

Comment: Ok, now I use oficial docker php, mariadb and nginx, everything compile ok